# Let $D$ $=$ $\{6,8\}$ and let $E$ $=$ $\{3,4\}$. Express $\mathcal{P}(A)$ $\times$ $E$ as a set using a list of all its elements.

Tags: solution-verification, set-theory

Let $D$ $=$ $\{6,8\}$ and let $E$ $=$ $\{3,4\}$. Express $\mathcal{P}(A)$ $\times$ $E$ as a set using a list of all its elements.

**My attempt**

$\mathcal{P}(D)$ $=$  $\{${$\emptyset$}$\}, ${6}, $\{8\}$, $\{6,8\}\}$

Since $\mathcal{P}(D)$ $\times$ $E$ $=$ $\{$($x$,$y$)$ | x $ $\in$ $\mathcal{P}(D)$ $\wedge$ $y$ $\in$ $E$}$  \Rightarrow \mathcal{P}(D)$ $\times$ $E$ $=$ (({$\emptyset$},$3$), ($\{\emptyset$},$4$), ($\{6\}$,$3$), ($\{6\}$,$4$), ($\{8\}$,$3$), ($\{8\}$,$4$), ($\{6,8\}$,$3$), ($\{6,8\}$,$4$))

Comment: Your solution is correct.

Comment: nit: it's $\emptyset$, not $\{\emptyset\}$.